# png image copied to another image php

Tags: php, image, png

I'm trying to add a png image onto another image. The only problem I have is that the png image is creating a transparent background around it instead of having the background of the other image.

Here's the image:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $img_name = "image_" . date("U") . ".png";
    $whoareyou_src = imagecreatefrompng('who-are-you.png');

    create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src);
    print "<img src=". $img_name .">";

    function  create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src) {
        $im = @imagecreate(800, 610) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 128, 128);  // teal

        // imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
        $success = imagecopy($im, $whoareyou_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($whoareyou_src), imagesy($whoareyou_src));
        echo "Image Copy: " . $success . "<br>"; // testing

        imagepng($im, $img_name);

        imagedestroy($im);
        imagedestroy($whoareyou_src);
    }

?>
```

I thought of setting the background to transparent might help:

```
imagecolortransparent($whoareyou_src, imagecolorallocate($whoareyou_src, 0, 0, 0));
```

But this did not change anything.

**Update**

Tried to use `imagecopyresampled` and `alpha` settings but still the same result:

```
<?php
    $img_name = "image_" . date("U") . ".png";
    $whoareyou_src = imagecreatefrompng('who-are-you.png');

    create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src);
    print "<img src=". $img_name .">";

    function  create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src) {
        $im = @imagecreate(800, 610) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
        imagealphablending($im, false);
        imagesavealpha($im,true);

        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 128, 128);  // teal

        $success = imagecopyresampled($im, $whoareyou_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($whoareyou_src), imagesy($whoareyou_src), imagesx($whoareyou_src), imagesy($whoareyou_src));
        echo "Image Copy: " . $success . "<br>";

        imagepng($im, $img_name);

        imagedestroy($im);
        imagedestroy($whoareyou_src);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Your description is quite unclear, do you want to have transparent or teal background? Have you tried to prefill background image with your color using `imagefill`?

Comment: What I'd like to have is the teal background as well. Same result when using `imagefill`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src);
print "<img src=". $img_name .">";

function  create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src) {
    $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(800, 610) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
    imagealphablending($im, false);
    imagesavealpha($im,true);

    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 128, 128);  // teal

    // imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
    $success = imagecopyresampled($im, $whoareyou_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($whoareyou_src), imagesy($whoareyou_src));
    echo "Image Copy: " . $success . "<br>"; // testing

    imagepng($im, $img_name);

    imagedestroy($im);
    imagedestroy($whoareyou_src);
}
```

?>

Comment: I've actually just tried that, the same result though. I'll update my question.

Comment: I've just noticed you added `imagecreatetruecolor`! I didn't add that my bad.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
    $img_name = "image_" . date("U") . ".png";
    $whoareyou_src = imagecreatefrompng('who-are-you.png');

    create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src);
    print "<img src=". $img_name .">";

    function  create_image($img_name, $whoareyou_src) {
        $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(800, 610) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 128, 128);  // teal
        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 800, 610, $background_color);

        // imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
        $success = imagecopy($im, $whoareyou_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($whoareyou_src), imagesy($whoareyou_src));
        echo "Image Copy: " . $success . "<br>"; // testing

        imagepng($im, $img_name);

        imagedestroy($im);
        imagedestroy($whoareyou_src);
    }

?>
```